# Is there a generic system delegate that takes 2 types and returns the second

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I am looking for something like Action but I want it to be

```
delegate U ReturnAction<T,U>(T param);
```

Is there already a system delegate for this? I just don't want to reinvent the wheel. I did the same thing when I first needed a Predicate and then realized it existed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i think you need

```
Func<T, TRet>
```

It has various overloads

```
Func<TRet>
Func<T, TRet>
Func<T1, T2, TRet>
Func<T1, T2, T3, TRet>
```

Comment: wow, I'm getting old, thats exactly what I wanted. I knew it existed but had a total brainfart.

Comment: jejej that was an easy one !!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at Func

```
delegate TReturn Func<T1,TReturn>(T1 arg1);
```

The 3.5 framework contains several overloads of func.  From 0 to 4 arguments are defined.